# C# Regex - Match certain char followed by number/identifier

Tags: c#, regex

I'm in trouble with a `Regex` which seems to have never been asked here.
I have to replace the char `a` followed by a `whitespace` (or not followed), but necessarly followed by a `number` (the number must not be replaced).

I have this Regex:
`[aA]\s.(?<=\d)*`
and this is the result:

### [image: 1]]

using `(?<=\d)*` I wanted to try to match but not capture the number immediately after the character following (or not) from the space, but obviously it doesn't work, also because "\d" does not include the identifiers.
Identifiers can be a series of numeric or alphanumeric characters without a defined length, nor a sorting of the letters in case it was alphanumeric.
They can be `A54N3`, `Z4G78` or `8454` or `4AZ7` or `7` or `A1`, `1A`. Combinations always change.

I'd want to match ONLY the `a` before the number `8`(or any other number, or an identifier like `N574A`) and replace that char with `art`, but leaving the number /identifier as it is, so result should be: `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'art8` or `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'artN574A`, and if the target string was `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'a8` or `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'aN574A`, (so without whitespace) result should be: `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'art8` or `agricoltura n 6 sensi dell'artN574A`

So the generic rule should be:
`Match [aA] followed by an optional space then must be followed by a number or an identifier that must not be captured`

Is it possible to do such a thing? What could be the solution?
Thank you so much!

#### UPDATE

Using the `\\b([aA])\\s*([A-Za-z]*\\d[\\dA-Za-z]*)\\b` pattern seems to replace correct values, [here](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5baA%5d%29%5cs*%28%5bA-Za-z%5d*%5cd%5b%5cdA-Za-z%5d*%29%5cb&i=agricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a+8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27aaAN574A&r=%241rt%242) is the demo

Comment: Capture what you need to keep and use `${x}`  where `x` is the Group ID (1-based)

Comment: sorry @WiktorStribiżew, I'm sure it's my fault, but honestly I don't see how that post can match with my question

Comment: What you need to keep is wrapped with a capturing group, the rest is just matched. Well, no idea how else we can help you since your rules are too vague. You say it must be followed with a number and then you say it can be an identifier. You might probably try `Regex.Replace(text, @"([aA])\s*([A-Z]*\d[\dA-Z]*\b)", "$1rt$2")` (see [**demo**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%5baA%5d%29%5cs*%28%5bA-Z%5d*%5cd%5b%5cdA-Z%5d*%5cb%29&i=agricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a+8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a+N574A&r=%241rt%242)), but you should precise the rules.

Comment: As you suggested i edited question pointing out immediately that the field that must be present but excluded from the match can be both a number and an identifier.
So, the rule is: match [aA] followed by an optional space then must be followed by a number or an identifier that must not be captured.

Comment: Ok, so, `.(?<=\W)*` was meant to match an identifier? It is the same as if you tried to match any char with `.`. And the number/ID can be captured, since you can always restore it in the result with a backreference. See the solution in my previous comment, does it help in any way? The problem with the question is still that you did not reveal the identifier pattern requirements.

Comment: To make the question on topic, please explain why you used `.(?<=\W)*` and what the identifier pattern must be. Please also fix the title as I closed the post because you asked to replace something followed by something else, which is done with capturing groups/backreferences, or with lookarounds.

Comment: I actually noticed that there were a few errors in the application, and I made the necessary changes (i hope). By the way, your pattern `([aA])\s*([A-Za-z]*\d[\dA-Za-z]*\b)` seems working. I still do other tests to confirm it

Comment: So, that means an identifier is an alphanumeric string that contains at least 1 digit.

Comment: If you confirm it and add to the question, I think the question will be answerable.

Comment: Yes, it's absolutely correct. Thank you!

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes i confirm your pattern works, i just had to add `\b` on `(\b[aA])` to not consider the case in which the character is the last letter of a word followed by the space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b([aA])\s*([A-Za-z]*\d[\dA-Za-z]*)\b
```

Replace with `$1rt$2`. See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%28%5baA%5d%29%5cs*%28%5bA-Za-z%5d*%5cd%5b%5cdA-Za-z%5d*%29%5cb&i=agricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a+8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a8%0d%0aagricoltura+n+6+sensi+dell%27a+aAN574A&r=%241rt%242)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `([aA])` - Group 1 (referred to with `$1` from the replacement pattern): `a` or `A`
- `\s*` - 0 or more whitespaces
- `([A-Za-z]*\d[\dA-Za-z]*)` - Group 2 (referred to with `$2` from the replacement pattern): an alphanumeric whole word that contains at least one digit:

  - `[A-Za-z]*` - zero or more ASCII letters
  - `\d` - a digit
  - `[\dA-Za-z]*` - 0+ digits or ASCII letters (replace `\d` with `0-9` to match ASCII digits only, or pass `RegexOptions.ECMAScript` flag to `Regex` constructor)
- `\b` - word boundary.

Comment: This pattern works good! In my case, the word boundary works even better inside parentheses, especially the first one: `(\\b[aA])\\.\\s*([A-Za-z]*\\d[\\dA-Za-z]*\\b)`

Comment: @MatteoPietroPeru It is common (best) practice to keep `\b` outside of capturing groups for better performance.

Comment: I adjust my previous comment: word boundary works correctly also outside parentheses!